# Splitting the values of column in csv and write in new column using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have an excel column as shown below :-

```
FileName               Coordinates
abc.text               0 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44
```

I want the output to be in this fashion :-

```
FileName               Coordinates                   Label    X-1      Y-1      X-3      X-4
abc.txt                0, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44       0      0.41     0.42     0.43     0.44
```

I have written the below code and before it worked for me, dont know what I am mission in this specific case :-

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('path/to/Coordinates_v3_updated.csv')

df[['Label', 'x1','y1', 'x2', 'y2']] = df['Coordinates'].str.split(" ",expand=True)

print(df)

df.to_csv('path/to/save/to/Coordinates_v3_updated_v1.csv', index=False)
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `df[['Label', 'x1','y1', 'x2', 'y2']] = df['Coordinates'].str.split(" ",expand=True)`

with `df[['Label', 'x1','y1', 'x2', 'y2']] = df['Coordinates'].str.split(", ",expand=True)`